# Identifiability in this Hierarchical Dynamic Factor Model

Tags: time-series, identifiability

I am studying the dynamic factor model presented in "Dynamic Hierarchical Factor Models" by Moench, Ng, and Potter. A copy can be found [here](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/REST_a_00359) if you're interested in reading on your own. Consider the three-level model in vector form:

\begin{align}
X_{bt} &= \Lambda_{G.b} (L) G_{bt} + e_{Xbt} \\
G_{bt} &= \Lambda_{F.b} (L) F_t + e_{Gbt} \\
\Psi_{F} (L) F_t &= \epsilon_{Ft}, \quad \epsilon_{Ft} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_F)
\end{align}
where

- $X_{bt} = \left( X_{b1t}, X_{b2t}, \ldots, X_{bNt} \right)^{\top}$ is the $N \times 1$ vector of observations in block $b$,
- $G_{bt} = \left( G_{b1t}, G_{b2t}, \ldots, G_{b K_{Gb} t} \right)^{\top}$ is a $K_{Gb} \times 1$ vector of block-level factors
- $F_t = \left(F_{1t}, F_{2t}, \ldots, F_{K_F t} \right)^{\top}$ is a $K_F \times 1$ vector of common factors,
- $\Lambda_{G.b} (L)$ and $\Lambda_{F.b}(L)$ are distributed lag matrix polynomials in $L$,
- $\Psi_F (L)$ is a autoregressive matrix polynomial in $L$.

The error terms in the first two equations are assumed to be normally distributed autoregressive processes, so 
\begin{align}
\Psi_{X.b} (L) e_{Xbt} &= \epsilon_{Xbt}, \quad \epsilon_{Xbt} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_{Xb}) \\
\Psi_{G.b} (L) e_{Gbt} &= \epsilon_{Gbt}, \quad \epsilon_{Gbt} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_{Gb})
\end{align}

In the current form, the model **is not** identifiable because "there could exist an invertible polynomial matrix $\Theta (L)$ of arbitrary order such that the common component $\Lambda (L) F_t$ is observationally equivalent to $\tilde{\Lambda} (L) \tilde{F}_t$ , where $\tilde{\Lambda} (L) = \Lambda (L) \Theta (L)$ and $\tilde{F}_t = \Theta (L) ^{-1} F_t$. To achieve identification, two-level models often assume that $\Lambda (L) = \Lambda$ is a constant lower triangular matrix of order 0 where the elements on the diagonal have a fixed sign. The assumption of constant, lower
triangular factor loading matrices can still be used to handle multiple
factors in a hierarchical setting."

> **Question:** How exactly does assuming that $\Lambda_{G.b} (L) = \Lambda_{G.b}$ and $\Lambda_{F.b}(L) = \Lambda_{F.b}$ are constant lower triangular matrices of order 0 lead to the model being identifiable?

I can immediately see how it eliminates the existence of an invertible polynomial matrix, but even after making this assumption couldn't I use the SVD of $\Lambda_{G.b}$ and $\Lambda_{F.b}$ to obtain observationally equivalent representations?